# How to integrate x^2 exp(-x^2/8)?

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

$\int x^2 e^{-x^2/8}$

I want to know the theoretical value of mean of N(0,sd=2) and then every number is squared. The r code is:

mean(rnorm(10000,0,2)^2)

Comment: Try using **integration by parts** on $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\left(x e^{-x^2/8}\right)\, dx.$$ (Integrate the $x e^{-x^2/8}$ and differentiate the $x$.) Also make sure you remember how to calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2/8}\, dx$.

Comment: Your text is confusing. What your formula is calculating is $E(X^2)$ when $X\sim N(0,2^2)$. In particular, it is not $(E(X))^2$, as your text suggests. In any case, you should be able to find the value by recalling standard properties (mean, variance etc) of the Normal distribution. (There’s a factor of $1/(\sqrt{2\pi})$ missing in the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ has normal($0,\sigma=2$) distribution and you want $E(X^2)$, use the fact that
$$\operatorname{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Another method than the one mentioned in the comments is to consider a more general version of your problem. Let
$$\mathcal{G}(a)=\int_0^\infty e^{-a x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}a^{-1/2}$$
Then your integral is given by $-\frac{d}{da}\mathcal{G}\,\big|_{a=1/8}$. Computing it, you find that your integral is
$$8\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\pi}.$$